# Adding size of image using react Cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to ask if there is any way to determine the size of the image in react-bootstrap's Cards.
I have a code like this and I wanted to determine the size of the image, but in documentation the src to the image is in `""` and they put the size after `/` but as for my code, I have src, which calls props, so I have to do it using `{}`. So how can I determine the size of the image?

```
<Card.Img variant="top" src={props.image_url} alt="no image found" />
```